# Automatic add Users to another class after authorization and how to avoid issues after changing field's names of old data

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using standard `django.contrib.auth.models User`.
And I have some registered users.
I want to create a `class Member`:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    id_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ninja")
```

And want to relate new users with the `class Member` automatically.
I have several questions.

1. How can I relate the classes automatically after authorization?
2. How can I change a field from another class, like a `class Goal`, where I'm using now `id_user`, but after creating the new `class Member` I need to change the name of field like `id_member`. So old data have old name of field - `id_user`, but after changing I need to give the new name `id_member`.
3. I have found a solution to avoid these two questions.
   Like in my pic:
   [image]

### I leave everything as it is. I do not touch old data. There is no need to create automatic connections between User and Member classes. But I still have to manually add users to the Member class. And this double link, I doubt it.

Of cource, I want to know the answers of all my questions. Please, if you don’t mind dispelling my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my questions myself.

1. I used signals:

app/signals.py. You need create this file manually in your project:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from accounts.models import Member

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_ninja(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Member.objects.create(id_user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_member(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.member.save()
     except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Member.objects.create(id_user=instance)
```

In your apps.py. I have just writed def ready(self):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals

__init__.py:
default_app_config = 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'
```

2. In this case, I uncommented and commented the field with foreignkey, which related to my new model. Sometimes, you can get issues.
   In this case, you need to know how migrations works and please don't use migrate --fake, if you don't know what will happened.
3. I haven't any issues with double model links yet. So, signals work for me pretty well.